# Is it possible to usa a custom-defined palette in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, color-palette, viridis

I would like to use a custom defined palette in drawing a graph with ggplot2. I take just an example made with viridis:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(10000), y = rnorm(10000)), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex() + coord_fixed() +
  scale_fill_viridis() + theme_bw()
```

My idea is to use the following palette:

```
palette <- c("#771C19", "#AA3929", "#E25033", "#F27314", "#F8A31B", 
              "#E2C59F", "#B6C5CC", "#8E9CA3", "#556670", "#000000")

library(scales)
show_col(palette)
```

[image]

I supposed to use `scale_colour_manual(values = palette)` but it looks like it doesn't take my custom-defined one. I am doing some kind of mistake?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(10000), y = rnorm(10000)), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex() + coord_fixed() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = palette) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `scale_color_manual` which will only work for discrete variables mapped on the `color` aes. As you have a continuous variable which is mapped on the `fill` aes one option would be to use `scale_fill_gradientn`:

```r
set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)

palette <- c(
  "#771C19", "#AA3929", "#E25033", "#F27314", "#F8A31B",
  "#E2C59F", "#B6C5CC", "#8E9CA3", "#556670", "#000000"
)

ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(10000), y = rnorm(10000)), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex() +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = palette)
```

[image]

Comment: Clear, easy and simple! thak you!